# Stochastic gradient descent for multi variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Please let me know if I am doing a wrong implementation of Stochastic gradient descent

```
train_x = np.asanyarray(train[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB']])
print('Initial training matrix: ',train_x)
ones = np.ones([len(train_x),1]) # Column Array of Ones  
train_x = np.concatenate((ones, train_x), axis=1)
print('New Training Matrix: ',train_x)
train_y = np.asanyarray(train[['CO2EMISSIONS']])
theta_predicted = np.ones(4)
print('Intial coefficient Matrix:', theta_predicted)

test_x = np.asanyarray(test[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB']])
ones_test = np.ones([len(test_x),1])
test_x = np.concatenate((ones_test, test_x), axis=1)
test_y = np.asanyarray(test[['CO2EMISSIONS']])

#stochastic Gradient descent implementation
n_epochs = 10
epoch = 1
#tolerance = 1e-06
learningRate = 0.001
noOfTrainingSamples = len(train_x)
while epoch <= n_epochs:
    temp_theta_predicted = theta_predicted.copy()
    i = 0
    while i < noOfTrainingSamples:
        print('Training sample: ',train_x[i])
        yPredicted = np.dot(theta_predicted, train_x[i]) # Hypothesis constructed
        j = 0
        while j < 4 :
            theta_predicted[j] = theta_predicted[j] - learningRate*((yPredicted -   train_y[i])*train_x[i][j])
            j = j + 1
        print('Coefficient Matrix After training sample ', i , ' of Epoch ', epoch, ' is: ', theta_predicted)
        i= i+1
    epoch = epoch +1
print ('---------------------------------------------- ')
print ('Final Coefficient Matrix: ', theta_predicted)
print ('No Of Epochs: ',epoch)

predictedValues = np.empty(len(test_x), dtype=object)
i = 0
while i < len(test_x):
    predictedValues[i] = np.dot(theta_predicted, test_x[i])
    i= i+1

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
errorRMSE = mean_squared_error(test_y, predictedValues, squared=False)
print("Root Mean Square Error: ", errorRMSE)
```

Results:

```
Final Coefficient Matrix:  \[21.21311438  4.52426003 14.18695555 12.90354722\]
No Of Epochs:  11
Root Mean Square Error:  29.44761000890938
```

But the linear_model.LinearRegression() function from sklearn gives the output as

```
Coefficients:  \[\[10.50501595  7.34469047  9.88861763\]\]
Residual sum of squares: 533.39
Variance score: 0.87
Root Mean Square Error:  23.095210179651897
```

Is my code wrong? Why does function from sklearn give only 3 coefficients when it should be 4, because 3 features and one intercept term.

Here is the code from inbuilt library

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

```
df = pd.read_csv("FuelConsumption.csv")

# take a look at the dataset
df.head()
df.describe()
print(len(df))
cdf = df[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_CITY','FUELCONSUMPTION_HWY','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB','CO2EMISSIONS']]
cdf.head(9)
viz = cdf[['CYLINDERS','ENGINESIZE','CO2EMISSIONS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB']]
viz.hist()
plt.show()

# Split Datatset
msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8
train = cdf[msk]
test = cdf[~msk]

from sklearn import linear_model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
x = np.asanyarray(train[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB']])
y = np.asanyarray(train[['CO2EMISSIONS']])
regr.fit (x, y)
# The coefficients
print ('Coefficients: ', regr.coef_)

#Prediction
y_hat=regr.predict(test[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB']])
x=np.asanyarray(test[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB']])
y = np.asanyarray(test[['CO2EMISSIONS']])
print("Residual sum of squares: %.2f"
      % np.mean((y_hat - y) ** 2))

# Explained variance score: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Variance score: %.2f' % regr.score(x, y))

# Accuracy calculation
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
test_x=np.asanyarray(test[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB']])
test_y = np.asanyarray(test[['CO2EMISSIONS']])
test_y_ = regr.predict(test_x)
errorRMSE = mean_squared_error(y, y_hat, squared=False)
print("Root Mean Square Error: ", errorRMSE)
```

Comment: For clarification purposes can you put in the code that you use to train/predict with the sklearn model?

Comment: Added the code from inbuilt library

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is wrong I think sklearn keeps the intercept term separate from the rest of the coefficients. Take a look [at the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), and in particular the example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
>>> X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]])
>>> # y = 1 * x_0 + 2 * x_1 + 3
>>> y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
>>> reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
>>> reg.score(X, y)
1.0
>>> reg.coef_
array([1., 2.])
>>> reg.intercept_
3.0...
>>> reg.predict(np.array([[3, 5]]))
array([16.])
```

Comment: but the coefficient values are very different in the two methods

Comment: Ah I thought I was answering your primary question when you asked "Why does function from sklearn give only 3 coefficients when it should be 4, because 3 features and one intercept term." As for why different coefficients, your SGD solution may not have converged